# Issue trying to pass a stored procedure function result using dbml to WPF via Item Source

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, stored-procedures

First, sorry about my english because it is not my native language. I will try to be specific. I usually create stored procedures in a mdf connected to my VB project using Windows Forms. What I do is that I add an dbml file, and then I drag and drop my store procedures to the functions columns in the dbml designer. Then, I'm able to do something like this: (in this case, my DBML file name is "Tutorials Data)

```
 Public Class Form1

  Private status As New TutorialsDataDataContext

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As    System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Dim rec = status.TutorialStatus()

    ComboBox1.DataSource = rec

  End Sub
End Class
```

TutorialStatus() returns 3 values. A code like that will work well in a Windows Form project, and when I run it, it would show me those values of the database. The problem is that "DataSource" property doesn't seems to exists in WPF applications, and the one which resembles it most is the "ItemsSources" property. The problem is that, that property returns three values that read: "tutorial_keeper_real.tutorialstatusresult" in the ComboBox.

The code that I wrote in WPF project, looks like this:

```
Class MainWindow 

  Private status As New TutorialsDataDataContext


  Private Sub winMain_Loaded(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Loaded
    Dim rec

    rec = status.TutorialStatus()

    ComboBox1.ItemsSource = rec


  End Sub
End Class
```

It returns the action made by the function to the database but not the actual values. There is ANY way to achieve what I use to do in a Windows Form project using WPF? Please, don't tell me to do this via Ado.net or something like that because I know about that but I would prefer to do it this way... or I rather return to Windows Form. Well, thank you all!! And sorry about my poor english... it is not my native language.

PD. If someone have any doubt about how I create the function based on a stored procedure, using a dbml, you can see this video as this guy do it well:

[Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=9f0dhtQdeHY)

Comment: Ok I asked at MSDN. When they respond, I'll immediately post the solution. If anyone is willing to help in the meantime, I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I finally got over it. I received this well accurate answer from MSDN:

"You can get the raw data from procedure. It looks OK. But in WPF, we should binding the property which you want display in XAML Code or Code behind. Something looks like, we want display ID property in Combo Box,"

XAML CODE:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox x:Name="Combo" DisplayMemberPath="ID" />
</StackPanel>
```

C# Code (can be converted to Visual Basic with a tool)

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<Raw> RawData = new List<Raw>() 
        {
            new Raw(){SearchData = "Jimmy", ID="001"},
            new Raw(){SearchData = "Jack", ID="002"},
            new Raw(){SearchData = "Jim", ID="003"},
            new Raw(){SearchData = "Jerry", ID="004"},
            new Raw(){SearchData = "Jason", ID="005"},
            new Raw(){SearchData = "Jeff", ID="006"},
        };
        this.Combo.ItemsSource = RawData;
    }
}

public class Raw
{
    public string SearchData { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }
}
```

The result will be a Combo Box showing the ID's!

And that's it!! It really helped me and hope this serve as well for you guys.